# Create a new Date format

Tags: date, hive, impala

I have a dataset containing a date field in the format of MM/dd/yyyy, my goal is to create a table with the same date format but with timestamp format (at the end, there should be an option to execute date functions on that, if it is int or string date function will not work.)

Things I tried:
my column name: as_of_date

1) cast(unix_timestamp(`as_of_date`, "MM/dd/yyyy") as timestamp)
     i/p -> 01/03/2006, o/p ->2006-01-03 00:00:00
     problem - I do not want extra zeros in the output. substr is not working on the date function

2) If i keep the value as string, date functions does't work.
   day('01/03/2006')
   input: '01/03/2006' , output:null (but expected 3)

Can you please help me a date format that already existing or help me to create a new date format for my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this once

use **unix_timestamp** function to match your **input date format** then use **from_unixtime** function to change the **output format** then cast to **date** type.

```
hive> select date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("03/06/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd"));
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2018-03-06  |
+-------------+--+
```

**In Impala:**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("03/06/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd");
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2018-03-06  |
+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Thank you @shu I tried in Hive, it worked fine.    
hive> select date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("03/06/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd"));
OK
2018-03-06

But when i try the same in Impala i get an error message:
[impala] > select date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("03/06/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd"));
ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
Encountered: DATE
Expected: ALL, CASE, CAST, DISTINCT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, STRAIGHT_JOIN, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER
CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: Try without casting to date type in impala **select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("03/06/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd");**

Comment: So when creating table i need to mention these way right: <column name> from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(column name, "MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd"); Will it work? or any modifications need to be done

Comment: Thank you, yesterday i did some more analysis and found from_unixtimestamp will be resulting in a string :( i can not apply date functions. my am i to apply date functions and the output format should be yyyy-MM-dd. Can you please help me. @Shu

Comment: Use timestamp with **yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.0** this format then load the data. while retrieving the data use **to_date(<column_name>)** to extract only date from the timestamp column.